# Not able to understand the output of C program

Tags: c, output

There's this code in C

```
int fun()
{
  static int num = 40;
  return num--;
}

int main()
{
  for(fun(); fun(); fun())
  {
    printf("%d ", fun());
  }
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

the output comes out to be: 38 35 32 29 26 23 20 17 14 11 8 5 2

I'm not able to figure out why the program doesn't continue to print beyond 2. i.e. in the negatives .shouldn't it continue printing ... -1 -4 -7....infinite loop  Can anyone explain ?

Comment: Whoever made this code crafted it so that the condition in the `for` loop would make `fun` return `0`.

Comment: In C `0` is interpreted at `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole magic happens inside your `for()` loop.

The basic format is like this:

```
for (<pre-iteration>; <condition>; <post-iteration>)
    <code>
```

Code inside **pre-iteration** will be executed once before the first iteration/loop.
Code inside **condition** is evaluated before each and every iteration. If the resulting value is `true`, the loop continues, if it's `false`, the loop is left.
Code inside **post-iteration** is executed after each and every iteration.

To make the whole code easier to understand, it's important to know that you're able to write such a `for()` loop using a `while()` loop as well:

```
<pre-iteration>
while (<condition>) {
    <code>
    <post-iteration>
}
```

Back to your example:

```
for (fun(); fun(); fun())
{
    printf("%d ", fun());
}
```

Using a `while()` this can be written like this:

```
fun();
while (fun()) {
    printf("%d ", fun());
    fun();
}
```

Since `fun()` will return the value of the static value `num` and then decrement it by `1` the first iteration will look like this:

```
// This is going to be the first call, so the static variable is initialized: num = 40
fun();                    // returns 40; num = 39
while (fun()) {           // returns 39; num = 38 (true -> loop continues)
    printf("%d ", fun()); // returns 38; num = 37 (-> 38 is written to console)
    fun();                // returns 37; num = 36
}
```

The next iteration (code before the loop is no longer executed for obvious reasons):

```
fun();                    // no longer executed
while (fun()) {           // returns 36; num = 35 (true -> loop continues)
    printf("%d ", fun()); // returns 35; num = 34 (-> 35 is written to console)
    fun();                // returns 34; num = 33
}
```

This continues till the last iteration:

```
fun();                    // no longer executed
while (fun()) {           // returns 0; num = -1 (false -> loop exits)
    printf("%d ", fun()); // no longer executed
    fun();                // no longer executed
}
```

---

> I'm not able to figure out why the program doesn't continue to print beyond 2. i.e. in the negatives .shouldn't it continue printing ... -1 -4 -7....infinite loop Can anyone explain ?

Yes, it might continue, but only if that specific call to `fun()` wouldn't return `0`, i.e. set the initial value of `num` to `41` and the program will run indefinitely (or at least till the return value happens to be `0` at some point).

Answer (score 5):

`fun()` is evaluating to `0` here:

```
for(fun(); fun(); fun())
//         ^
```

`0` is the equivalent of `false` in C, so the loop is exiting.

The code relies on the fact that `num - 1` is a multiple of 3, as `fun()` is evaluated once at the start of the loop and then 3 times every loop. If, for example, you changed the definition to

```
static int num = 41;
```

`fun()` would return `0` in the wrong place and your loop would continue into the negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at what happens in the second call to `fun()` in the `for` loop. The first time the loop is entered, `fun()` has been evaluated once already, so `num` is `39`. The second time we get to the loop, `fun()` has been executed three more times, so it is now `36`. This process continues, until eventually, the second call to `fun()` returns `0`. In C, `0` means `false`, so the loop terminates at that stage.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(fun(); fun(); fun())
```

second part of `for()` loop is a condition - if `fun()` returns 0, which is interpreted as false, the loop terminates. lately i got a brain fart and wrote a statement that condition is true only for positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

When

```
printf("%d ", fun());
```

is run, fun() has value 2
Then the last fun() in the next command is executed to increase the counter (normally):

```
for(fun(); fun(); fun())
```

fun()  is 1.

Then the condition to continue the for loop is performed, which is the second fun() in:

```
for(fun(); fun(); fun())
```

At this point, fun() is 0 which makes the for loop stop.

Answer (score 1):

When you print `fun()`, you do not see the actual value of `num`, but the value of `num+1`.

This is because you are using a postfix-decrement (`num--`) and not a prefix-decrement (`--num`).

So when you 2 is printed, the actual value of `num` is 1.

At the end of this iteration, `fun()` is invoked, setting `num` to 0.

At the beginning of the next iteration, `num` is evaluated as false and the `for` loop is terminated.